# One Project - Multiple Programs

Tags: java, eclipse, project, package, program-entry-point

I am using Java to write a mid scale product that has multiple programs.

You can think of this project as a MMOG, with server-side, client-side, and other programs.

Since Java has this notion of Projects and Packages, can I put everything in one single Project but separated by Packages? Or do I have to resort to a Project for each individual program?

If there is a way to put all together, that'll be great, because right now I am getting a "Could not find Main" error.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there's a formal notion of "project" in Java.

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about what you mean by a package? There is no obvious limitation on this. I have several projects where I use ant scripts to package everything up into multiple jar files per project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them all in one project with packages, as long as you have a main function in a class for each package. However, when you build the project, it will go through everything, and if you decide to export, everything will be included in the jar file. On the other hand, if you separate them into projects, everything will be neat and clean. They will be separate and you can export them separately, however, if the projects need access to one another, you must make sure to include each project on the build path of the dependent projects.

Comment: That's exactly what I have been doing, which is giving me the "Could not find Main" error. Also, Each package have multiple Classes that have their own Main. I do have in each package a Main class that calls the mains of other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's quite common to separate a large product into multiple projects. In Eclipse, you can add projects to your buildpath. Right click on your "main" project, select Build Path > Configure Build Path and click the "Projects" tab. There you'll see options to add required projects to your buildpath.